# Creating a custom line chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Trying to create a custom line chart in which there is only one simple line, with a gradient background - the background of every part of the line is determined according to the y-value at that point (changes in values are guaranteed to be mild).

I'm having trouble with the basic configuration. This is my code:

**js**:

```
// General definitions
var HEIGHT, MARGINS, WIDTH, formatDay, lineFunc, graph, graph_data, weekdays, x, xAxis, y, yAxis;
WIDTH = 360;
HEIGHT = 130;
MARGINS = {
  top: 20,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 20
};

graph = d3.select("#graph");

// Define Axes
weekdays = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"];
formatDay = function(d) {
  return weekdays[d % 6];
};

x = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([
  d3.min(graph_data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }), d3.max(graph_data, function(d) {
    return d.x + 1;
  })
]);

y = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([
  d3.min(graph_data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }), d3.max(graph_data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
]);
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(formatDay);
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize(10).orient("left");

// Line Function
lineFunc = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
  return x(d.x);
}).y(function(d) {
  return y(d.y);
}).interpolate("basis");

// Define Line Gradient
graph.append("linearGradient").attr("id", "line-gradient").attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse").attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0)).attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(200)).selectAll("stop").data([
  {
    offset: "0%",
    color: "#F0A794"
  }, {
    offset: "20%",
    color: "#F0A794"
  }, {
    offset: "20%",
    color: "#E6A36A"
  }, {
    offset: "40%",
    color: "#E6A36A"
  }, {
    offset: "40%",
    color: "#CE9BD2"
  }, {
    offset: "62%",
    color: "#CE9BD2"
  }, {
    offset: "62%",
    color: "#AA96EE"
  }, {
    offset: "82%",
    color: "#AA96EE"
  }, {
    offset: "82%",
    color: "#689BE7"
  }, {
    offset: "90%",
    color: "#689BE7"
  }, {
    offset: "90%",
    color: "1AA1DF"
  }, {
    offset: "100%",
    color: "1AA1DF"
  }
]).enter().append("stop").attr("offset", function(d) {
  return d.offset;
}).attr("stop-color", function(d) {
  return d.color;
});

// Draw Line
graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", lineFunc(graph_data));

// Draw Axes
graph.append("svg:g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")").call(xAxis);
graph.append("svg:g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + ",0)").call(yAxis);
```

**style**

```
#line-gradient {
  fill: none;
  stroke: url(#line-gradient);
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linejoin: "round";
}
```

**Sample data**

```
graph_data = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 22
}, {
  x: 2,
  y: 20
}, {
  x: 3,
  y: 10
}, {
  x: 4,
  y: 40
}, {
  x: 5,
  y: 5
}, {
  x: 6,
  y: 30
}, {
  x: 7,
  y: 60
}]
```

What i'm getting looks like this:

[image]

Can any of you D3.js experts tell me what I'm doing wrong, and what needs to change in order for my line to be a line rather than an area, having the line background gradient explained above, and round edges?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: To make it a line, you need to give the `path` that generates the line a `fill` of `none` and an appropriate `stroke-width` and `stroke`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/gu4y7fk8/

You should give the `path` a class name, like this:

```
graph.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class","chartpath")
    .attr("d", lineFunc(graph_data));
```

And then the CSS styling you have should be on that `path` element rather than the `lineargradient` element

```
.chartpath {  /*note: not #line-gradient*/
  fill: none;
  stroke: url(#line-gradient);
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linejoin: "round";
}
```

I also fixed up a couple of other things:

1. Missing `#` on a couple of the color codes, so changed (`color: "1AA1DF"` to `color: "#1AA1DF"`
2. I changed the max y value for the gradient from 200 to 60, so that the changing color gradient of the line is more visible in the example (`.attr("y2", y(200))` to `.attr("y2", y(60))`)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Henry! I actually figured out the css class and missing pound sign, the rest was a walk in the park, but you, my friend, went above and beyond with that fiddle. Thank you!

Comment: I know it's not in the scope of the question, but do you happen to know how to make this same graph's width responsive? (where both the x-axis and the graph line are updated on the fly). Been having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? - I've found it useful before for responsive width: http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/28/responsive-charts-with-d3/

Comment: I have, gave it another look, working now. Thanks again!